# There exists a Morse function on $M$ taking different values at different critical points

Tags: differential-topology, morse-theory

> Let $M$ be a compact smooth manifold (without boundary). Prove: there exists a Morse function $f$ on $M$, such that $f$ takes different values at different critical points.

This is an exercise on the chapter about vector fields, flows and Morse functions in a Differential Topology book (Chinese version).

**Definition.** A smooth function $f:M\to\mathbb R$ is called *a Morse function* if all critical points of $f$ are non-degenerate: if $p\in M$ is a critical point, and $(U,\varphi)$ is a local chart around $p$, then the Hessian of $\tilde f=f\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is non-degenerate at $\varphi(p)$, i.e.,
$$\mathrm{det}\left(\frac{\partial^2\tilde f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}(\varphi(p))\right)\neq0.$$

**My thoughts.** Firstly, since $M$ is compact, $f$ must take its maximum and minimum on $M$, so we have at least two critical points. Hence, a natural idea is: can we construct a Morse function with only two critical points? The answer is no, because of [Reeb's sphere theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Reeb+sphere+theorem), which sates that if there exists a Morse function on $M$ with only two critical points, then $M$ is (topologically) homeomorphic to the sphere! What’s more, I constructed a Morse function on $S^n$ with only two critical points. That is the height function: $f(x_1, \cdots, x_{n+1})=x_{n+1}$ for $x\in S^n\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$. It can be verified using the definition and stereographic local charts. However, what about general manifolds?

I'm not good at geometric stuffs. If my question is silly, forgive me please. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Here's an idea to get you started (with the intuition just being perturbation):  let $g$ be a bump function supported on a neighborhood $U$ of your critical point $p$.  Let $h = f + \epsilon g$.  Then for small enough $\epsilon$, $h$ is also Morse (what can you say about the critical points?).

Comment: @AlvinJin Thanks for your comment! Sorry for the late reply. I understood your hint in this way: take an arbitrary Morse function $f$, then by compactness we have only finitely many critical points, and the value of $f$ at these points may be the same. Assume that $f$ takes the same value at $\{p_1, \cdots, p_k\}$, where $p_i$ are critical values, then we perturb $f$ around $p_i$ by $\frac ik \epsilon g$ for some small $\epsilon$ and bump function $g$. In this way, the values of perturbed $f$ at $p_i$ are different and critical points aren’t changed. Am I on the right track?